# Robot Framework: Click Element using Execute JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, robotframework

I have a xpath selector    `xpath=//input[@id=image]`, I want to click on this element using the keyword Execute Javascript ,please help me right the statement

I tired the  statement

```
${Element} = Get WebElement xpath=//input[@id=image]
Execute JavaScript  arguments[0].click(),${Element}
```

It throws an syntax error.

Comment: What is the reason you want to do this with Javascript when there are specific SeleniumLibrary keywords for this behaviour?

Comment: Because when i use Click element keyword , i get the error  WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <table id="ext-comp-1179" cellspacing="0" class="x-btn x-form-file-btn x-btn-icon">...</table> is not clickable at point (1165, 410). Other element would receive the click: <input id="image" name="image" class="x-form-file" type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" size="1">. so when google i see that it would work if i try it with javascript

Comment: This sounds to me like the real problem you need to solve. There is an overlay on your element, or the ID is not as unique as you think.

Answer (score 4):

Following this link [Is there a way to get element by XPath using JavaScript in Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-using-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver)
I have created a keyword for clicking hidden elements. It also works for visible elements.

```
JS Click Element
[Documentation]
...     Can be used to click hidden elements
...     Dependencies
...         SeleniumLibrary
...         String
[Arguments]     ${element_xpath}
# escape " characters of xpath
${element_xpath}=       Replace String      ${element_xpath}        \"  \\\"
Execute JavaScript  document.evaluate("${element_xpath}", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null).snapshotItem(0).click();
```

Answer (score 4):

> Use below code to click using javascript with XPath in robot framework

```
${ele}    Get WebElement    //*[text()='Logout']
Execute Javascript    arguments[0].click();     ARGUMENTS    ${ele}
```

Comment: THANKS!!! tried for hours on this page... https://obstaclecourse.tricentis.com/Obstacles/41040   only thing works was your solution!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding element and then passing to JS, you can directly find element by ID and click it using JS.

```
Execute JavaScript    document.getElementById("element-id").onclick()
```

Comment: Please could you do it with xpath, it could be really helpful, as we use xpath throughout our project

Comment: There is not direct function available in JS like getElementByXpath.  Please check this lnik - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-using-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver