# Robot Framework: Click button using execute javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, robotframework

This is the web inspection

```
<span jsslot="">
<button class="LkLjZd ScJHi IfEcue HPiPcc KXT7c" jsaction="click:yTqzwd" jsname="HxVe9c" autofocus="">Install</button>
</span>
```

I want to click on this element using the keyword Execute Javascript. I try like this

```
Execute JavaScript      document.evaluate("//button[contains(text(),'Install')]",document.body,null,9,null).singleNodeValue.click()
```

After run test, it is PASS but no any action on web. It's still at the same. Could you please help?

---

I've already found the solution. According to there are several iframe, so should be select expected iframe before execute above command like this

```
Select Frame      xpath=//*[@id="obj"]/div[5]/iframe
Execute JavaScript      document.evaluate("//button[contains(text(),'Install')]",document.body,null,9,null).singleNodeValue.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Robot Framework: Click Element using Execute JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48181988/robot-framework-click-element-using-execute-javascript)

Already there is a answer for your question in the above link. Just copied and pasting one of the solution here.

```
${element_xpath}=       Replace String      ${element_xpath}        \"  \\\"
Execute JavaScript  document.evaluate("${element_xpath}", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null).snapshotItem(0).click();
```

Also there are multiple solution in the link, try that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can get more idea to resolve.